# Ubuntu16.04 LTS dpkg: Error Proccessing Package

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

Good Day!

Hello Everyong, I just wanted to ask for some help from the community on how to resolve this issue. I encountered this every time I tried to update or install a new application, such as PHP 7.4. I`ve been looking for a solution, but I couldn`t find any. If someone who is an expert on Ubuntu or has more experience with this OS can provide me with a way or solution to resolve this issue, I would be very grateful. Please see below error for your reference:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.17) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-firmware (1.157.23) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-142-generic
cp: omitting directory '/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules'
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/udev failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-142-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-210-generic (4.4.0-210.242) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-firmware; however:
  Package linux-firmware is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 4.4.0.210.216); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.17) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-142-generic
cp: omitting directory '/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules'
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/udev failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-142-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for linux-image-4.4.0-210-generic (4.4.0-210.242) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 4.4.0-210-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-210-generic
cp: omitting directory '/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules'
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/udev failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-210-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-210-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
 initramfs-tools
 linux-image-4.4.0-210-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` file exists.

If it does not exist, it has to be created (as a file): `sudo touch /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rule`

If it is a directory instead, it has to be removed: `sudo rm -r /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`.

Finally run `sudo apt-get update, sudo apt-get upgrade, sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: Hi @monkrus, I was able to resolved this issue by following the instruction guide here https://itsfoss.com/dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1/